# listview with sections with highlighted title

Tags: android

I am working on an app where i have to implement in it a listview with different sections, the sections should have a highlighted title.
I have no idea how to do it and i am new at android programming and i found nothing on the internet .. can anyone help me please ?
I have tried several tutorials but nothing worked for me.

Thanks.

The listview should look like that:

**title 1**

A

B

C

**title 2**

A

D

G

Comment: [Searched](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+listview+with+section+headers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=4kHrU56HFIuJ8QfD54CwDw)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a List-Activtiy or ListView with section wise, you need following thing--

```
Header XML
Normal ListRow XML
Main Activity with ListView
Adapter class
```

Create XML name item1.xml inside res/layout folder.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="text"
          android:visibility="visible"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FF000000"
          android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Create XML name item2.xml inside res/layout folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
         <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textSeparator"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="text"
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
         android:background="#000" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

ListAdapter Class

//Adapter Class
       private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

MultipleItemsList where you can set the adapter

```
public class MultipleItemsList extends ListActivity{

private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem("Sameer Blog " + i);
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Ahmad " + i);
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

This would look like this

[image]

For more info http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-listview-with-section-header.html

Answer (score 1):

1) You can refer [Listview with sections](http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android)

2) You can also use Expandablelistview instead of using list view. You can refer [ExpandableListDemo](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/). 
For your sections You can set different layout file.

For setting your listview always open you can use following code.

```
myListview.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Doing nothing
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link which was explained clearly with an example

http://javatechig.com/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android